# Bootstrap 4 beta how to add image after text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an issue with adding an image in "menu" section at the last item "Kava so sebou" after the text. (the picture should be center vertically and the row should look like the other items above. Any suggestions? Thank you for your help. I just learn bootstrap and I'm a girl. (hilarious combination)

Custom css

```css
.menu {
  padding: 70px 0px;
}
.menu .block > p {
  color: #9D9D9D;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  padding: 40px 133px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu .block .pricing-list {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.menu .block .pricing-list ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 0 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu .block .pricing-list ul li {
  padding: 21px 0px;
}
.menu .block .pricing-list ul li .item .item-title {
  position: relative;
}
.menu .block .pricing-list ul li .item .item-title h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  background: #fff;
}
.menu .block .pricing-list ul li .item .item-title .border-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border: 1px dotted #C9C9C9;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.menu .block .pricing-list ul li .item .item-title .border-bottom-coffee {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border: 1px dotted #C9C9C9;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.menu .block .pricing-list ul li .item .item-title span {
  float: right;
  color: #938463;
}
.menu .block .pricing-list ul li .item .item-title span {
  float: right;
  color: #938463;
}
.menu .block .pricing-list ul li .item .item-title img {
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.menu .block .pricing-list ul li .item p {
  padding: 12px 0 0px;
  color: #949494;
}
```

```html
 <!-- Start Menu list -->
    <section id="menu" class="menu">
     <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="block">
                        <div class="pricing-list">
                            <div class="title">
                             <div class="container">
                             <ul>
                                <li class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="300ms" data-wow-delay="1100ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 300ms; animation-delay: 1100ms; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <div class="item-title">
                                            <h2>Pivo 10 0.5L</h2>
                                            <div class="border-bottom"></div>
                                            <span>€ 1.20</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>Zlatý Bažant, Staropramen</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="300ms" data-wow-delay="1200ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 300ms; animation-delay: 1200ms; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <div class="item-title">
                                            <h2>Káva so sebou </h2>
                                            <div class="border-bottom"></div>
                                            <span>€ 1.20</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>Štrbské Presso</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>                          
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- block close -->
                </div><!-- .col-md-12 close -->
            </div><!-- .row close -->
        </div><!-- .containe close -->
    </section><!-- #price close -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read this part of bootstrap docs, it will be very helpful for tasks like this: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/media-object/

In this case, you should set your container div class to `media`, cover your text to div with class `media-body` and add `media-object` to div with your image.

Then, you only need to make some changes in your css, and it will look perfect.

It is the fast-made code I've made:

```
<div class="item">
        <div class="item-title media">
                <div class="media-body" style="white-space: nowrap;padding-top: 50px;">
                       <h2>Káva so sebou</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="media-object">
                       <img class="align-self-center mx-auto=" d-inline-block="" text-nowrap="" src="./images/coffee.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="border-bottom-coffee" style="position:relative;"></div>
                <span>€ 1.20</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advice. 
This worked for me

```
<li class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="300ms" data-wow-delay="1200ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 300ms; animation-delay: 1200ms; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-title media">
      <h2>
        Káva so sebou
        <p>Štrbské Presso</p>
      </h2>
      <div class="border-bottom"></div>
        <div class="media-object">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="./images/coffee.jpg">                                               
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
        <span>€ 1.20</span>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</li>
```